# Bitcoin wiki docs, account or address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-accounts

> **listtransactions**   [account] [count=10] [from=0]
>   Returns up to [count] most recent transactions skipping the first [from] transactions for account [account]. If [account] not provided it'll return recent transactions from all accounts.

The above is pasted from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

My question: The page refers to both account(s) and address(es). The wallet can easily generate additional addresses to receive coins but, how can a wallet have more than one account?

This documentation does not look correct to me.

Shouldn't it read

> If [**address**] not provided it'll return recent transactions from all **addresses**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct as written.  Accounts are just a grouping of addresses.  You generally create accounts with the **getaccountaddress** call.

This [wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained) provides more detail on what accounts are all about.